# How to upload pdf file via intent to email app

Tags: android, file, android-intent, gmail, implicit

I am new to android. I tried the following code to send a file via gmail but I am getting errors:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"SOMEFOLDER"+File.separator+file_name);
                i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/*");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,file);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abcd@gmail.com"});
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```

Comment: Well tell your errors directly in your post. Behind `errors:`

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(file)` You cannot use that anymode since Android N/7. You have to use an uri from  `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` now.

Comment: In addition, use a concrete MIME type (`application/pdf`), not a wildcard (`application/*`). *Your* app is sending the content; *you* are responsible for telling the recipient what the MIME type is of that content.